# JavaScript Array with multiple items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a array with multiple fields in it.

For Example:

```
var person1 = {firstname:"Bob", lastname:"Smith", middlename:"happy"};
```

The problem I have is that I have 5000 variables I want to create so it would become:

```
var person1 = {firstname:"Bob", lastname:"Smith", middlename:"happy"};
var person2 = {firstname:"John", lastname:"Jones", middlename:"Long"};
..
var person5000 = {firstname:"Jim", lastname:"Cook", middlename:"Shorty"};
```

I think it would be silly to have 5000 lines of code to declare the variables.
So I want to be able to declare the variables on page load and then later assign the values to each.

I was trying to do this using the following code but I am guessing I am doing something wrong.
(I am loading some dummy data into the variables for testing)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
    var person = new Array (firstName:"", lastName:"", middleName:"");
    for (var i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
        person[i] = {firstName:"First"+i, lastName:"Last"+i, middlename:"Middle"+i};
    }


alert(person1["firstName"]); // should alert First1
alert(person6["lastname"]);  // should alert Last6


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I was hoping to later in my code set the value using:
(I am pretty sure this code should work, but can't test it since I can't declare the variables correctly)

```
person1[firstname] = "Terry";  // should replace First1 with Terry
```

And then to receive a value using:

```
alert(person1[firstname]);  // should alert Terry since it was changed
```

Anyone know what is wrong with my code since it's not returning the value ?
I am guessing I am declaring the variables wrong? If so how should I declare them ?

Comment: [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) != [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be confused about the difference between arrays and objects in Javascript. Arrays have numeric indexes, objects have named properties. So the initialization

```
new Array(firstName:"", lastName:"", middleName:"");
```

makes no sense. Not to mention, it's not valid Javascript syntax; `property: value` pairs can only be used in object literals, not in argument lists. If you use `new Array(...)`, the argument should either be a single number, which is the size of the array to allocate, or a list of initial array element (with no `property:` prefixes. But the preferred way to create a new array is simply with the `[]` literal for an empty array; it will grow as necessary when you assign to it.

When you create an array, you don't get separate variables for each element. You access them using `array[n]` notation.

```
// Create an empty array
var person = [];
// Fill up the array
for (var i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
    person[i] = {firstName:"First"+i, lastName:"Last"+i, middlename:"Middle"+i};
}

// Access elements
alert(person[1].firstName);
alert(person[6].middleName);
// Change elements
person[1].firstName = "Terry";
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me.. Makes sense now.

Comment: I was following the example from: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp and must of got confused when following there examples.

Comment: Although I generally recommend against w3schools.com (they're prolific, but the quality is poor), that page does have a section explaining the difference between objects and arrays, and explaining when to use one versus the other.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work as you intended:

```
var person = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
    person[i] = {firstName:"First"+i, lastName:"Last"+i, middleName:"Middle"+i};
}

alert(person[1]["firstName"]);
alert(person[6]["lastName"]);
```

As pointed out by others, the `person` array is filled with objects, not arrays. You can use either property or [associative array syntax](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) with them.